# Bypass GitHub branch protection rule

Tags: github, azure-devops, cicd

we have a GitHub repository enabled with Branch project policy for Master branch with default pull request reviewers.

There is a node.js pipeline created in azure DevOps which on success tries to commit a file to Master branch, however it is failing because of the branch restriction policy.

I've tried with the option "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests" but that didn't work.

How can I override the policy and push the file during pipeline execution.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when we create a new pipeline, we need to choose *Where is your code?*. When we choose GitHub, it will auto link the GitHub to Azure DevOps with creating a GitHub App named Azure Pipelines in GitHub. Your pipeline will run with the Azure Pipelines identity without using your personal GitHub identity.

So, you should add the GitHub App named Azure Pipelines to the "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests".

[image]

After this, the pipeline can bypass GitHub branch protection rule.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*While directly overriding branch policies from a pipeline isn't generally recommended due to security and governance concerns,*

*Do the followings and see it it works out for you*:

1. Exempt the Pipeline Service Account:

Grant the Azure DevOps Pipeline service account (usually in the format "Project Collection Build Service (Organization)") the "Bypass policies when pushing" permission for the Master branch. This allows the pipeline to push directly without a pull request.
Caution: Exercise careful judgment with this approach as it could circumvent intended safeguards.
2. Create a Dedicated Service Account:

Create a separate GitHub user specifically for pipeline actions.
Grant this user the "Bypass policies when pushing" permission.
Use this user's credentials in the pipeline to push changes.
Advantage: Isolates pipeline activities from other users and limits potential impact.
3. Leverage a Personal Access Token:

Generate a personal access token (PAT) with write access for the GitHub repository.
Use the PAT in the pipeline to authenticate and push changes.
Caution: Store the PAT securely as a secret variable in Azure DevOps.
4. Restructure the Pipeline:

Consider modifying the pipeline to create a pull request instead of direct commits.
This aligns with best practices and maintains policy enforcement.
You can automate pull request approval using appropriate permissions for the pipeline service account.
5. Explore GitHub Actions:

If possible, consider using GitHub Actions instead of Azure DevOps, as it offers more granular control over branch protection policies within the GitHub environment.
Important Considerations:

Security: Carefully evaluate the implications of bypassing policies to ensure security and compliance.
Alternative Solutions: Explore alternative approaches, such as creating a separate branch for pipeline-generated changes or using pull requests for review and approval.
Best Practices: Prioritize solutions that adhere to best practices for code quality and governance.